# getVar parameter text to replace underscores with spaces

Tags: php, joomla, parameters, str-replace

In Joomla I am pulling back a paramater with the following code:

```
return JRequest::getVar('product');
```

This pulls back great, but the parameter has 'underscores' as follows:

**Google_Docs_Security**

I want to pull back the above, but replacing the above 'unerscores with spaces and have tried the following, but it's not working:

**Google Docs Security**

```
return JRequest::getVar('product');
$product= str_replace ("_", " ", $product);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return str_replace ("_", " ", JRequest::getVar('product'));
```